# Does Dark Souls II have a way to be purchased with all DLC?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I noticed that on Steam, Dark Souls II is sold with "Scholar of the First Sin" with the main game, and then each subsequent DLC is $10 after that, making the game a total of $70. Is there a chance of there being a "game of the year" edition, similar to Skyrim's, where I could get all of the DLC with the main game for a reasonable price?

Answer (score 10):

Scholar of the First Sin *is* the version you are looking for. It includes all the DLC content as well as being the 64-bit version which has enhanced graphics and some "extra features".

From the Steam [store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/335300/):

> The definitive edition of DARK SOULS™ II. DARK SOULS™ II: Scholar of the First Sin includes **all the DARK SOULS™ II content released to-date** in one package and much more!

Emphasis is my own

Answer (score 5):

The "Scholar of the First Sin" edition includes all of the DLC as well as a few other differences.